# Resource Qualifiers for Deskop WPF, HighDPI or Multilanguage

Tags: c#, wpf, desktop, highdpi

For Windows Apps there is the concept of resource qualifiers. You can add different image sizes or languages, and WPF choses the right one for you.

```
en-us\logo.scale-100.png
en-us\logo.scale-140.png
fr-fr\logo.png
```

More Infos: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh965372.aspx

I would really like to use this concept for my desktop WPF applications. Do you have any ideas how i could do that? I didn't find any solution which supported different languages and different scaling sizes at the same time.

Since Windows 8.1 an application can rescale if you move it to another screen. If the resources get updated if this happens it would be perfect.